# jquery traversing method versus selector method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use the best practice as far as selecting and traversing through the dom. I heard that different method and selectors have different performance.
Is it true that using traverse method in JQUERY is quicker performance wise than using selectors? If so why is it quicker?

Comment: Can include example `html` , element to select ?

Comment: Here is a good read: [**jQuery Learning Center**](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)

Comment: It's a great question but if you're just starting out, don't overthink it.  The worst thing you can do is start second-guessing yourself into "should I select or traverse" and end up writing horrible code that does the worst of both.  It will come naturally soon enough the more jQuery you write and  the more comfortable you get with jQuery selection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Is it true that using traverse method in JQUERY is quicker performance wise than using selectors?`
**YES**

`why is it quicker?`

First of all, If you want to select just one element with `id` or `class` and the element is in the top of the DOM then there is no performance issue you can use any of them.

But when you are talking about going deeper or your element stay as child one and can be in any level in the Dom here we need to think.

As for example:

```
<div id="mdiv">
    <ul>
        <li>one<li>
        <li>two<li>
        <li>three<li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now you want to select the last `li`.

so you can do in selection way like:

```
$("#mdiv ul li:last")
```

or,

```
$("#mdiv ul > li:last")
```

**OR**
in traversing way

```
$("#mydiv").find("ul").children("li").last();
```

Now definitely the the traversing one will be faster.
**WHY??**
just take one  thing in consideration the **String parsing**.
In first case the String will need to be parsed to translate what does it mean and the search the DOM accordingly.
When in the second case you gave direct command so it will do the DOM searching without any parsing.